# Create a star using Canvas API given inner and outer radius of star points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use the CanvasAPI to create a star, but the requirements of the function are to have a prompt for the inner and outer radius of the star points. 
What I'm really confused about is how to create each point of the star and have it rotate variably given the two inputs.
Sadly the only code I'd have to share is the 4 lines that create the inner and outer radii, so any help is welcome.

Comment: Without going into canvas specifics (which I don't know enough about) you would need an extra parameter: the number of 'points' (for lack of the proper English term) of the star you want to create. E.g.: A six-pointed star has 6 outer and 6 inner points spread evenly over 1 rotation ( = 360 degrees)

Comment: By "prompt" do you mean Window.prompt()?